# Feature request: LaTeX preview in *comments*

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, comment

I would like to request that a **preview be generated when writing comments**, the same way that one is generated when writing a question.

This is particularly relevant in math forums where LaTeX equations are often needed in comments.

(apologies if this topic was already discussed)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see that ever happening on SE. Comments are second-rate denizens of this website, and a $\rm\LaTeX$ preview would be expensive in terms of resources (specifically display real estate).

Comment: I am agree with previous comment. Any case you can edit any formula using a post *Ask Question* and after copy and paste this text in your comment (finally discard the draft *Ask Question*).

Comment: what about a button/link that shows a preview only on request in a popup?

Comment: This might help at least users who use TamperMonkey: [An attempt to add real-time previewing for comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21746). (I do not, so I cannot really check whether the userscript still works.)

Comment: What I sometimes do:  Write my comment in an Answer box, then copy it into the comment space and erase the answer without ever posting it.

Comment: @GEdgar and user243301 what you are suggesting is a workaround, what I'd like is something integrated -- of course users can preview latex equations through a variety of other means, but you also want to make their life easy by eliminating repetitive steps!  I do not see the user benefit of asking them to create a question, copy/paste it into a comment box on another page, and delete the question

Comment: I just use the Answer box on the same page as the comment I want to write.

Comment: @MartinSleziak The feature works as I am using it till date and it works perfectly.

Comment: Just get experience with $\rm\LaTeX$ and develop your very own built in compiler. The code you can put in a comment box is not that complicated anyway. :)

Comment: Also, let's all remember that answers (with mathjax and such) belong in *answer fields*, and comments ought not to be answers.  A comment, if using mathjax, ought to be short enough to edit within the grace period allowed for editing comments.

Comment: About your words concerning my comment, now I see that I didn't understand well your idea (you want a tool, while my proposal it was like a patch), thus I'm sorry maybe I was impulsive commenting myself idea